# How do you disable touchscreen gestures on Fedora/GNOME?

Tags: firefox, fedora, gnome, touchscreen, gestures

I'm creating a touchscreen project on Fedora 23 (using GNOME 3.18.2) that requires a fullscreen Firefox (or Chrome) window that the user cannot close using the touchscreen.

However, we realized that there's a built-in gesture as part of GNOME that opens the Activities menu when you swipe right, starting at the left edge of the screen. This even happens when our Firefox or Chrome window is fullscreen/in kiosk mode.

There have been a lot of suggestions around the internet for how to disable multitouch gestures in GNOME, but I haven't seen a way to disable the left-swipe gesture.

Is there a way to do this in Fedora?

**EDIT:** My boss has a related question that he asked to have added to the post:

"We're trying to run Firefox in "kiosk" mode, but noticed that there is a "feature" in fedora gnome-shell 3.13.91 that allows for users to edge drag from the left side of the screen and bring up the dash -- invalidating the kiosk.

I believe the code for this feature is located in the gnome-shell code https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell in the files `/js/ui/edgeDragAction.js` and `js/ui/viewSelector.js` -- but I could be completely wrong.

I believe edge drag sensitivity is set in `/js/ui/edgeDragAction.js` (See Code below)

And the action is added to `js/ui/viewSelector.js` (See code below)

What is the best recommended method for turning this off?    Writing our own Gnome Extension?   Can we override these methods or change the thresholds easily?

For example:

```
const EDGE_THRESHOLD = 20; <- change to 0
const DRAG_DISTANCE = 80; <- change to 1000
```

**EDIT 2:** With the help of Florian Müllner, we wrote a Gnome extension with the following Javascript code, and it seems to have fixed our problem:

```
/*
 * Disable all of the touchscreen gestures.
 */
function enable() {

global.stage.get_actions().forEach(a => a.enabled = false);

}

/*
 * Re-enable the touchscreen gestures.
 */
function disable() {

    global.stage.get_actions().forEach(a => a.enabled = true);
}
```

Comment: Try different window manager, which will also consume less resources (which does not matter though when running Firefox or Chrome)

Comment: To do this, would I install something like gnome-classic-session, or does that have the same window manager as Gnome 3?

Comment: `dnf search "window manager"` will list available packages. Try which one works the best for you. For example selinux X-sandboxes are using metacity WM.